# Django: Annotate the count of the number of duplicate values for each object

Tags: python, django, annotations

I have a model called Product seen below. Products can have the same field 'bc_sku'.

```
class Product(models.Model)

    bc_sku                          = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    product_type                    = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    merchant                        = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    product_price                   = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

For example, imagine I had this list of objects

```
    bc_sku | product_type | merchant | product_price
    100    | good         | A        | 1.00
    100    | bad          | B        | 2.00
    100    | bad          | C        | 3.00
    101    | good         | A        | 7.00
    101    | bad          | B        | 5.00
```

What I'd like to do is create a query which annotates each "good" product with the count of the number of duplicates along with the minimum price for each 'bc_sku'. I would then like to be able to use these objects and values in a template.

```
    bc_sku | product_type | merchant | dup_count | min_price
    100    | good         | A        | 3         | 1.00
    101    | good         | A        | 2         | 5.00
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm struggling to get annotations and filters to make it work currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first wish was to use [window function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions), but unfortunately it is [not allowed](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333#comment:description)  to combine `annotate(Window(...))` and `filter(...)`

The answer is:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Count, Min

subquery = Product.objects.filter(bc_sku=OuterRef('bc_sku')).values('bc_sku')
                          .annotate(dup_count=Count('*'), min_price=Min('product_price'))
Product.objects.filter(product_type='good')
               .annotate(dup_count=Subquery(subquery.values('dup_count')), 
                         min_price=Subquery(subquery.values('min_price')))
```

You can find details on how this query works in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This looks as though it is going to work, however I am getting the error below: 

Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field.

Comment: Don't worry, I solved it!
I wrapped my SubQuery's in the ExpressionWrapper and then used output_field=DecimalField() to sort. Thanks ever so much for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear! :) What Django version do you use? I use 2.0 and it worked as expected when I tried it with definition and data you mentioned in the question

Comment: I am using 2.0.7.